# Shiny app with renderText function need to add new line

Tags: shiny, newline

I have a Shiny app that I use a `renderText()` call in. I have some pasted text but would like to add a new line between, however, it is ignoring `\n` in the paste/print calls.

I have tried:

```
print(paste("Line 1\n", "Line 2\n"))
```

However, that prints like:

```
Line 1 Line 2
```

I also tried:

```
print(paste("Line 1", "Line 2", sep = "\n"))
```

And that prints the same as the above line (all on one line). Both calls are wrapped in `output$t <- renderText({ [code here] })`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("value"),
  htmlOutput("value2")
)

server <- function( session,input, output) {

  output$value <- renderText({
    paste("Line 1", "Line 2", sep="\n")
  })

  output$value2 <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste("Line 1", "Line 2",sep ="<br/>"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]